# Query to select all record and counts the same value?

Tags: sql

This Table:

```
name | city
 --------
john   na
mary   ny
mary   in
```

Is there a query that returns all record and counts name duplictaed?

Result of query:

```
name | count(name)
 john   1
 mary   2
 mary   2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select o.name "Name", 
   (select count(*) from table_name i where i.name = o.name) "Count"
from table_name o;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS supports windowed aggregate functions.

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: OVER PARTITION O_O, what's that

Comment: [See example here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) The link is SQL Server but it is standard SQL. Doesn't work in MySQL though. You should tag your specific RDBMS if you don't want standard SQL answers.

Comment: i don't think my tiny mysql 5 can support it xD

Comment: @yes123 - Correct. I think recent versions of most other RDBMSs do but MySQL is left out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
 COUNT(name) AS cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name;
```